# What is purpose of this angularJS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, drop-down-menu

Could someone explain to me what this code does? I know that it fetches countries and push them to the list which is shown in a web page, but why? I think that $scope.countries = service.query() is enough or is this way to avoid Asynchronous Problems?

```
$q.all([$scope.address.$promise, $scope.countrys.$promise]).then(function() {
        if (!$scope.address.country.id) {
            return $q.reject();
        }
        return Country.get({id : $scope.address.country.id}).$promise;
    }).then(function(country) {
        $scope.countrys.push(country);

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descriptions in code comments. This is conditionally data loading process using promise mechanism. Try to specify your question more detailed if is is not enough for you

```
// if address and countries was loaded (probably from ajax request)
$q.all([$scope.address.$promise, $scope.countrys.$promise]).then(function() {
    // if address doesn't exist reject all actions
    if (!$scope.address.country.id) {
        return $q.reject();
    }
    // otherwise load country based on address field as a promise
    return Country.get({id : $scope.address.country.id}).$promise;
}).then(function(country) {
    // when loading process is finished add country to dataset
    $scope.countrys.push(country);
});
```

According to [`$q` service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

`$q.all([promise1, promise2, ...])`

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
>   all of the input promises are resolved.

Comment: THANKS! What $q.all is doing and it seems that the countries list is pushed only one country but I think not, somehow it is working like loop?

Comment: It is not like a loop. In your case it just ensure that `$scope.address` and `$scope.countrys` was correctly loaded before this processing will start. See my edit

Comment: But it populates the array somehow? My query is like that: $scope.countrys = Country.query({filter: 'address-is-null'});

Comment: In your example it populates array with only one object in second `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

`service.query()` will inevitably return a [promise](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html), which resolves when the asynchronous call completes. It would make no sense to set the scope property (which you will no doubt bind to some form of list) with a promise.

What the code is doing is waiting for the promise(s) to resolve, performing some logic, and setting the resulting data to a scope property.